# Replace text in a function in Google Sheet (with script)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to replace strings in a sheet. It works just fine for all my text values, but I have a problem with functions.

I have phone numbers that are imported but unfortunately, I get a `=+` placed in front of them.

So the values are not 555-8181, its =+555-8181.

When I try to use for example Replace it doesn't work, likely because the values are stored as a function, and not a string, but I can be wrong.

Any hints on what to do?

Example of what I have tried:

```
function RemoveErrorInPhonenumber() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetWithNumbers");
  var range = sheet.getRange("Z:AG");
  var rngA = range.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    rngA[i][0]=rngA[i][0].toString().replace("+", "");

  }
  range.setValues(rngA);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace `range.getValues();` through [`range.getFormulas();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())

And then implement

`rngA[i][0]=rngA[i][0].toString().replace("+", "").replace("=", "");`

> Two more suggestions:

- If you want to loop through all of your columns Z:AG, you need to create two nested `for loops`:

```
for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)  {
  for(var j=1;j<rngA.length;j++)  {
    rngA[i][j]=...
  }
}
```

- Do not loop through the whole range `Z:AG` - this will make your code very slow. Instead, loop until the last data containing row:

`var range = sheet.getRange("Z1:AG"+sheet.getLastRow());`

Comment: Ahh, getFormulas, so simple when you see it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting the strings into values (but you will have to remove the **`-`**  first).

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en

Comment: I'm getting an error doing that.

The easiest way is to change the format of the column to String (see below), but its not the best solution:

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Sheet").getRange("Z:Z").setNumberFormat("@");